# Is there any api for setting the initial position and rotation of a specific robot in webots

Tags: webots

I'm programming with a robot such as robotis op2.For some reasons, I want to set the initial position and rotation of the robot with the code rather than directly click the scene tree to change the field. Can i change the position (such as (0, 0.5, 0.1)) with any API ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a supervisor robot and use the [wb_supervisor_field_set_sf_vec3f()](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor#wb_supervisor_field_set_sf_vec3f) function to change the position of the robot. Similarly the rotation can be changed using [wb_supervisor_field_set_sf_rotation()](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor#wb_supervisor_field_set_sf_rotation). An example of this is provided [here](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/blob/master/projects/samples/devices/controllers/sample_supervisor/sample_supervisor.c).